# FeathersJS: server to server authentication

Tags: node.js, feathersjs

I just notice that there is a possibility to authenticate server side or client side pretty easily:
https://docs.feathersjs.com/authentication/readme.html

But those instructions rely on a javascript server/client.
Generically, how can I authenticate a server side (Microservice) with a simple cURL request? which has no email and it is not an actual user (server to server), let's assume I have the secret key.

**TL;DR** How can I convert this to a simple cURL request for server authentication:

```
app.configure(authentication({
    token: {
        secret: 'my-secret'
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the `feathers-authentication` module version. In v0.7.x:

```
curl 'http://localhost:3030/auth/local/' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{ "email": "user@example.com", "password": "secret" }'
```

In 1.x:

```
curl 'http://localhost:3030/authentication' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{ "strategy": "local", "email": "user@example.com", "password": "secret" }'
```

Both will return a token for the authenticated user.

Comment: there is no user nor email. Server to server.  Only secret needed in the JS api (for Server side) What should be the curl api in that case?

Comment: You need to create some way of authenticating that server. The CURL call will be the Passport authentication strategy you set up as `strategy` and the data it requires.